# Do I need User Permissions for basic Google Analytics?

Tags: flutter, permissions, google-play, app-store, google-analytics-firebase

I added Google Firebase Analytics in my Flutter Project. And I am getting basic Information like how many Users used the App, which App Version they are on, which Country they are from and devices they are Using. No User specifics at all, no events or other tracking Information.

Right now I am not asking the user for Permissions to do this.
So my question do I have to ask the User for this Information? Will the Google/Apple Store reject the App because of this?

I am not sure as I can't find that much Info for my case. I just added the Firebase Plugin and added the GoogleService-Info.json/GoogleService-Info.plist and thats it, no code in the App itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some research about it now and here are my findings.

According to Firebase website [here](https://firebase.google.com/policies/analytics), you are required to let the user now, any type of analytics that has been enabled per product. Here is the quote.

```
You are required to notify your App Users by disclosing the following information:

- The Google Analytics for Firebase features you have implemented.
- How you and third-party vendors use first-party cookies, or other first-party identifiers, and third-party cookies and similar technologies, such as identifiers for mobile devices (including Android Advertising ID and Advertising Identifier for iOS), or other third-party identifiers, together.
- How App Users can opt-out of the Google Analytics for Firebase features you use, including through applicable device settings, such as the device advertising settings for mobile apps, or any other available means.
```

For more information, I also recommend [checking this out](https://firebase.google.com/terms/analytics)

p.s.I think the best way to leasrn is to ask this to a lawyer or try it on the submission.

Comment: Yeah, I read that but I thought this is only for event tracking etc. But I guess I have to be safe here and just add it. Thanks!